# Regular expression for username with specific conditions

Tags: .net, regex, validation, expression

I need a regular expression for a regex validation.

The conditions are as below:

• The user can only use letters in lowercase (a-z), numbers(0-9), characters “_”, have a length of at least 4 characters and not be longer than 35 characters.

• The username can’t start or end with a “_”.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
/^(?!_)[a-z0-9_]{4,35}(?<!_)$/
```

Something like this should do the trick; validates the underscore restriction with a lookahead/lookbehind and then simply matches the allowed characters between 4 and 35 times.